# how to check if a singularity is isolated?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have a function $1/(\sin(1/z))$ and I must show if the singularities are isolated or not.

Is taking the limit of the number a little to the right and a little to the left enough?

If not, how can I prove it is isolated or note?

Comment: A singularity $p$ is isolated if there exists a punctured neighborhood of $p$ on which the function has no singularities. So (a) what are the singularities of this function and (b) which of those have such neighborhoods? It seems clear for this function that not all such singularities are isolated!

Comment: thanks! I noticed they are not, but I need to prove it, how can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all singularities. In your case, $z=0$ and all points $z$ such that $\sin \frac1z =0$, i.e. $\frac1z = n\pi$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $0 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n\pi}$, $0$ is not an isolated singularity, (though the other ones are).

Comment: I see, but is there a pattern to test them, a test or it's mostly different for other values?

Comment: I don't understand that question. Are you referring to this particular function, or the problem in general?

Comment: a problem in general, I get that a circle around my z0 must exist for every value, but I'm wondering how to make sure of that for any case

Comment: I doubt there's a completely general procedure, but for example, if $f=g/h$ is the quotient of two holomorphic functions, its singularities are automatically isolated (since zeros of holomorphic functions are isolated).

Comment: true! thanks for that